# Visual studio 2022 Want to move the program as IDE to my friend pc

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, operating-system

I Want to move program visual studio 2022 from my pc to my friend how can do this without us visual studio installer but by move files and put them to my friend to can write c++ code

try to move file from C:\Program Files (x86) an same location on my friend 's pc

Comment: Your question makes no sense. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022